# What is the word for "something that needs prompt attention and resolved quickly"

Tags: single-word-requests

We usually encounter some cases at workplace "something that needs prompt attention and resolved quickly" ,is there a professional word we can use for this casE?

Comment: Many occupations have specific names that are nomenclature for critical issues. I've worked in a warehouse where we had "Expedites" and in facilities with "STATs" and "Urgent Work." You may find that your specific field has such nomenclature by asking around or reading literature specific to your profession. I would recommend listing your profession and asking if there is a profession-specific nomenclature for such an issue if that is your intention.

Answer (score 1):

The word *emergency*  fits fairly well.  An emergency is a fairly urgent matter, and urgency seems to be at the heart of your question.

You could use the phrase *urgent matter* if you want to be a little less dramatic.